# IBM BLUEMIX - can someone show the server side code on bluemix for android application which uses cloudant database

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, server-side, cloudant

I am trying to develop an Android app using Bluemix as server. Please show me the sample code with simple use case of signup from android client to store the data in the cloudant database. I am comfortable with client side that is android. I want am not able to start in server side. please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? A lot of Bluemix Mobile tutorials are available from IBM and other vendors. Here's a list from IBM developerWorks: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/all-tutorials/.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your application stores data that other users shouldn't be able to access, so you should be looking at the one DB per user model. The web service running in bluemix with admin level access the Cloudant (You should use API keys). The web service would handle the creation of the user's database and passing the credentials to the user, there is an example of a web service to do this [here](https://github.com/glynnbird/onedbperuser).

Answer (score 0):

Link to documentation of Cloudant NoSQL DB service on Bluemix is at https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/index.html#web-console, sign-in with Bluemix id. When you click on one of the methods to access this service, last one is Bluemix applications it will point you to get started.